# Mock command line arguments for Python script with `optparse`?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optparse

A Python script that I want to use (called [`snakefood`](http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html)) is normally run from the commandline and takes commandline arguments, eg:

```
sfood /path/to/my/project
```

The parsing of the commandline arguments happens in a file called [gendeps.py](https://github.com/jd23/py-deps/blob/master/lib/python/snakefood/gendeps.py) using `optparse`. However, I want to use the snakefood module from another script. Is there a way I can somehow mock the passing of commandline arguments to `snakefood` or a way of rewriting `gendeps.py` so that it doesn't depend on `optparse` anymore?

Comment: Why don't you run it via `subprocess.call`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always assign a new list to `sys.argv`:

```
import sys

sys.argv = ['programname', '-iq', '-q', directory]
gendeps.gendeps()
```

`optparse` uses `sys.argv[1:]` as input when no explicit arguments have been passed in.

Comment: This answer is helpful. Just a small improvement:
`import os`

`sys.argv = [os.path.basename(__file__),, '-iq', '-q', directory]`