# How to call module written with argparse in iPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, bioinformatics, biopython, suffix-tree

I am trying to pass BioPython sequences to [Ilya Stepanov's implementation of Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm](https://gist.github.com/istepanov/6506508#file-lcs-py) in iPython's notebook environment. I am stumbling on the argparse component.

I have never had to deal directly with argparse before. How can I use this without rewriting main()?

By the by, [this writeup of Ukkonen's algorithm is fantastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english/9513423#9513423).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've had [a similar problem before,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000444/mock-command-line-arguments-for-python-script-with-optparse) but using `optparse` instead of `argparse`.

You don't need to change anything in the original script, just assign a new list to `sys.argv` like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from Bio import SeqIO
    path = '/path/to/sequences.txt'
    sequences = [str(record.seq) for record in  SeqIO.parse(path, 'fasta')]
    sys.argv = ['-f'] + sequences
    main()
```

Comment: Nice. Just add dummy `sys.argv` works like `sys.argv = ['foo']`.

Comment: i don't know for how long i have been searching for this solution, thanks!

Answer (score 56):

Using `args = parser.parse_args(args=[])` would solve execution problem.

or you can declare it as class format.

```
class Args(argparse.Namespace):
  data = './data/penn'
  model = 'LSTM'
  emsize = 200
  nhid = 200

args=Args()
```

Comment: For me this was the most useful way to add arguments to Jupyter notebook. Thank you

Comment: I didnt want to deep dive into the whole topic, just get my 3rd party code, called from a jupyter notebook, to work. This did.

Comment: such a simple trick, I don't know why I didn't think about it, Thanks !

Comment: Could someone elaborate on how to use this? I may be missing something because when I `print(args)` it shows `Args()`.

Answer (score 50):

An alternative to use argparse in Ipython notebooks is passing a string to:

`args = parser.parse_args()`
(line 303 from the git repo you referenced.)

Would be something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Searching longest common substring. '
                    'Uses Ukkonen\'s suffix tree algorithm and generalized suffix tree. '
                    'Written by Ilya Stepanov (c) 2013')

parser.add_argument(
        'strings',
        metavar='STRING',
        nargs='*',
        help='String for searching',
    )

parser.add_argument(
        '-f',
        '--file',
        help='Path for input file. First line should contain number of lines to search in'
    )
```

and

`args = parser.parse_args("AAA --file /path/to/sequences.txt".split())`

Edit: It works

Comment: @mithrado @rjurney Almost, this works: `args = parser.parse_args(['--file', '/path/to/sequences.txt'])`, i.e. you need to pass an array of strings where each element is an argument that would normally be separated by a space in the command line.

Comment: @jjs the way to split the sequence automatically is to use `shlex.split`: `args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split("AAA --file /path/to/sequences.txt"))`

Answer (score 28):

If all arguments have a default value, then adding this to the top of the notebook should be enough:

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['']
```

(otherwise, just add necessary arguments instead of the empty string)

Answer (score 4):

Clean `sys.argv`

```
import sys; sys.argv=['']; del sys
```

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3883#issuecomment-269131039

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using BioPython to extract the sequences and then editing Ilya Steanov's implementation to remove the argparse methods.

```
import imp
seqs = []
lcsm = imp.load_source('lcsm', '/path/to/ukkonen.py')
for record in SeqIO.parse('/path/to/sequences.txt', 'fasta'):
    seqs.append(record)
lcsm.main(seqs)
```

For the algorithm, I had `main()` take one argument, his `strings` variable, but this sends the algorithm a list of special [BioPython Sequence objects](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc16), which the re module doesn't like. So I had to extract the sequence string

```
suffix_tree.append_string(s)
```

to

```
suffix_tree.append_string(str(s.seq))
```

which seems kind of brittle, but that's all I've got for now.

Answer (score 3):

I face a similar problem in invoking argsparse, the string '-f' was causing this problem. Just removing that from sys.srgv does the trick.

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '-f' in sys.argv:
        sys.argv.remove('-f')
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code which works well and I won't worry about the environment changed.

```
import sys
temp_argv = sys.argv

try:
    sys.argv = ['']
    print(sys.argv)
    args = argparse.parser_args()
finally:
    sys.argv = temp_argv
    print(sys.argv)
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this small code in python:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-v_1", "--verbose_1", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

To write this code in Jupyter notebook write this:

```
import argparse

args = argparse.Namespace(verbose=False, verbose_1=False)
```

***Note:*** In python, you can pass arguments on runtime but in the Jupyter notebook that will not be the case so be careful with the data types of your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If arguments passed by the iPython environment can be ignored (do not conflict with the specified arguments), then the following works like a charm:

```py
# REPLACE   args = parser.parse_args()   with:
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818237/11750716

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to change any of the arguments and working mechanisms from the original argparse function you have written or copied.

To let the program work then there is a simple solution that works most of the time.

You could just install [`jupyter-argparser`](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-argparser/) using the below command:

```
pip install jupyter_argparser
```

The codes work without any changes thanks to the maintainer of the package.