# Spoof argparse in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I am trying to use a function that was written with argparse in a Jupyter Notebook. To do this I'm trying to "spoof" the argparse, but can't figure out how to do it. I found [this useful SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656777/how-to-call-module-written-with-argparse-in-ipython-notebook) but I'm still understanding something about argparse. Here's what I've got so far:

```
import sys
import argparse

sys.argv = ['--config-file', "my_config"]


def argument_parser():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--config-file", default="", help="path to config file")
    parser.add_argument(
        "opts",
        help="Modify config options",
        default=None,
        nargs=argparse.REMAINDER,
    )
    return parser
```

Then when I call `argument_parser()` I get

```
ArgumentParser(prog='--config-file', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

Then I try to parse the arguments with:

```
args = argument_parser().parse_args()
print("Commandline Args:", args)
```

The output is:

```
Commandline Args: Namespace(config_file='', opts=['my_config'])
```

My goal is to get an output like this:

```
Commandline Args: Namespace(config_file='my_config')
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
import argparse

sys.argv = ['--config-file','my_config']


def argument_parser():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--config-file", default="", help="path to config file")
    parser.add_argument(
        "opts",
        help="Modify config options",
        default=None,
        nargs=argparse.REMAINDER,
    )
    return parser

args = argument_parser().parse_args(sys.argv)
print("Commandline Args:", args)
```

You should pass the `sys.argv` to the `parse_args` method.

Output:

```
Commandline Args: Namespace(config_file='my_config', opts=[])
```