# An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. SystemExit: 2

Tags: python, jupyter, argparse

can anyone tell me how to make this code works in jupyter or any notebook
[image]
**Code**

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True, help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2, help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

**Error**

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

I've tried some solutions but none work

Comment: Have you checked out this SO answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656777/how-to-call-module-written-with-argparse-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: _use %tb to see the full traceback_ Did you try doing that?

Comment: `argparse` handles commandline arguments provided by the OS shell.  You can't do that in a notebook, since the commandline supplies arguments to the server.  Why are you trying to use argparse in a notebook?  What code is going to use that `args`?

Comment: It specifically looks like you are trying to run [this](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/). (So my question would be why not point to that in you post?) And so it says to save that code in a file called `detect_faces.py` right above that, as hpaulj is sort of getting at.  Because others had similar questions, the author even posted more about this, see [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/03/12/python-argparse-command-line-arguments/), in particular where it says, "but the honest truth is that nearly all of these errors can be avoided by ...

Comment: <continued> taking the time to educate yourself on command line arguments." Note that if you want to include use of an `.ipynb` file with `detect_faces.py` you can run the Python script file with the extension `.py` from inside the notebook file with extension `.ipynb` by using in a Jupyter cell `%run detect_faces.py --image rooster.jpg --prototxt deploy.prototxt.txt --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel`, or the appropriate variation.

Comment: I was going to add to the end of my last comment that I don't know if the output from `detect_faces.py` is in a form that Jupyter is going to handle and so you may not want to do that, but that is how you'd run a python script from inside a Jupyter `.ipynb` file: use in a cell `%run <script_prefix>.py <flags_&_arguments>`. See about the `%run` magic [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change "required=True" to "required=False" and add default path in your code to works in jupyter or any notebook.

Also need to add "ap.add_argument("-f", required=False)" in the end of line.

In your case code will work like this:

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=False, default="/content/your_image.jpg", help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=False, default="/content/your_prototxt.txt", help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=False, default="/content/your_model.caffemodel", help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2, help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
ap.add_argument("-f", required=False)
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

**Be sure to change default path with your own file path.**

Worked in Google Colab notebook.